# SWT Tree population

Tags: java, tree, swt

I have an SWT tree I've populated from a 2d array list but it's not coming out quite right. I'm trying to group the top tree items by item number, and I'm not having any luck with my algorithm. I've attached a picture to explain a little bit better. item 4324226 appears twice with a different child item, and I would like to group both children under one parent.

[image]

Here is my code for the tree. Any ideas? Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

```
    long[][] listOrders;
    listOrders = database.getUnfinishedOrders();


    for (int i=0; i<listOrders.length; i++) {
        TreeItem iItem = new TreeItem (tree, 0);
        iItem.setText (Long.toString(listOrders[i][0]));
        for (int j=1; j<listOrders[i].length; j++) {
            TreeItem jItem = new TreeItem (iItem, 0);
            jItem.setText (Long.toString(listOrders[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The picture didn't loaded.

Comment: works fine on mine roman? all it really showed though, was 2 different instances of "4324226" expanded with different numbers underneath them. I'm trying to group them under one 4324226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Michal Borek suggestion here is the code to group parent and children in a `Map<Long, Set<Long>>` data structure. It assumes that for every parent, repeated children should be included only once (else just replace `Set` by `List` and `LinkedHashSet` by `ArrayList`):

```
private Map<Long, Set<Long>> buildModel(long[][] originalModel) {
    final Map<Long, Set<Long>> model = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Set<Long>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalModel.length; i++) {
        model.put(originalModel[i][0], new LinkedHashSet<Long>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < originalModel.length; i++) {
        final Long key = originalModel[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < originalModel[i].length; j++) {
            model.get(key).add(originalModel[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return model;
}
```

And this is how to build the SWT tree:

```
long[][] listOrders = database.getUnfinishedOrders();
final Map<Long, Set<Long>> ordersModel = buildModel(listOrders);

for (Map.Entry<Long, Set<Long>> entry : ordersModel.entrySet()) {
    TreeItem iItem = new TreeItem (tree, 0);
    iItem.setText(entry.getKey().toString()); 
    for (Long child : entry.getValue()) {
       TreeItem jItem = new TreeItem (iItem, 0);
       jItem.setText (child.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose to create a model before (so group it) and add this to tree just after you do this.

This would be a lot better from design perspective. Because view stuff is separated from data stuff.

You could use a map to store list of elements of specific order.